# How to increase cache expiration date with firebase tools?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I cannot seem to make the max-age work properly with any file. I want to increase the expiration of the cache, and I've been trying to increase only the image time for testing purposes. Still, chrome and firefox state the max-age for the image as 3600 with this json file[image: Image shows the files structure and the firebase.json file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `source` for the header isn't matching the input path of images in that folder - it needs to start with a `/`:

```
{
  "firebase": "sistema-de-oficios",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "headers": [{
    "source": "/css/images/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
    "headers": [{
      "key": "Cache-Control",
      "value": "max-age=7200"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Also, make sure you're on the latest version of `firebase-tools` which is currently `1.1.4` at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was that slash, i already had the 1.1.4 version.